# Upload Multiple Input File in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Hi guys need help in my project how does laravel handle this in the backend?

How about if you have multiple input:

```html
Photo 1: 
<input type="file" name="name">
Photo 2: 
<input type="file" name="name">

    $file_upload = [];
    $("input[name=name]").each(function()){
      $upload_val = $(this).prop('files')[0];
      $file_upload.push($upload_val);
    }


   var data_post = new FormData(); 
   data_post.append('uploads',$file_upload);
   $.ajax({
  url: "app/upload",
  type: "POST",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data: data_post,
  success:function(res){
          console.log(res)
        }
   });
```

Comment: http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/ hope that helps

Comment: Hi @Demonyowh thanks for the link but the example there is multiple selected in one input type file:
<input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple />
but in my case i got individual input type file but it is many:
<input type="file" name="name">
<input type="file" name="name">

Comment: there's no difference since you're appending all the image in the same variable `uploads` so in the backend you should just call it by `$this->input('uploads');`

Comment: I'll try that thanks

Comment: if you have two inputs with same name in one form, when you submit the form you have only one input in backend. So if you want to upload two or more file you must select different names for every inputs. like `Photo 1: <input type="file" name="photo1"> Photo 2: <input type="file" name="photo2">`.

Comment: Hi Hakan my plan in the backend is to explode the appended values which is an array and do a for loop ..so yeah

Comment: so just change it from name="name" to name="name[]" and all your problem is solved. But if user does not upload first photo, you have no chance to know this and you assume he uploads only first photo.

Comment: acttually i can create a trappings in my javascript for that.. thx for the suggestion i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like

Your HTML

```
<input type="file" value="photos[]">
<input type="file" value="photos[]">
```

Your backend

```
$photos = $request::file('photos')
foreach($photos as $photo) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: should i still append like the way i append above? or is there any changes?

Comment: To submit your form via ajax you could do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/1072492